# How do I respond to my Professor's email, wherein he has mistaken my gender?

Tags: sentence-usage

I am a Chinese student. I was emailing a professor for graduate study opportunity. He replied with the title: *Dear Mr. Li* Actually, I am a female. Would it be a little strange if I told him in my reply? and how do I put this, should I say "I am a female?" Thank you very much.

Comment: Give him a call and acknowledge his Email,he'll know you're a female !

Comment: Hello!  I'm glad you were able to act on an answer you got last night.  But please, don't edit a new question into an existing one.  This question is, more or less, finished; if you want to ask another, please ask it separately.  Thank you!

Comment: What does it matter? Once you meet, he'll know your gender.

Comment: This may be more of an etiquette question rather than an English one, but you could soften the blow by saying that Wei is a woman's name, and let him deduce for himself that you are female.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - You're assuming that Wei is the O.P.'s real name (which may not be the case). Moreover, are you sure that Wei is always a woman's name? [This website](http://www.behindthename.com/name/wei) suggests otherwise; and [this one](http://www.gpeters.com/names/baby-names.php?load=fresh&name=Wei%20Li) suggests the professor's guess wasn't a bad one.

Comment: Actually - depending on your field, there can be systematic bias depending on your gender. (This is [well-documented](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/unofficial-prognosis/2012/09/23/study-shows-gender-bias-in-science-is-real-heres-why-it-matters/) at least for science).  Is it essential to correct his mistake immediately? :p

Comment: My field is Earth sciences. Actually I was thinking about this problem, too. But I don't think there is a need to worry about bias to women researchers in application process these days.

Comment: Off topic but I can't help myself. I have to say it. It's not a criticism at the edited title, which is much clearer but truth be said, I still prefer the original one; it had charm, I loved the alliterative sounds between email and female, and it was clear the asker was non native. I know the question title was a bit of a riddle  but it was almost musical, very catchy; *E-mail: I am a female?* [Kraftwerk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQIYEPe6DWY) would have made an entire song out of this title :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, just a heads up, in Chinese "Wei" isn't always a female name. One of the odd joys of having many characters that have once pronunciation. :D

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agree totally, "email, female" had a nice ring to it, and I loved it too, but I had to do what I had to do, seeing how the question attracted over 6k views.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about you reply like this:

> Dear Professor Smith,
>
> (content of your reply)
>
> Thanks and Regards, 
>   Ms. Li Wei

That avoids the issue of "correcting" him altogether. He would hopefully get the hint.

---

**Edit**: Per StoneyB's suggestion in the below comment, I changed *Miss* to *Ms.*.

Comment: PS: I usually avoid using a salutation with my own name, and it is considered impolite/imprudent by many, but in this case, an exception could be made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sometimes I think I can be casual with professors and sometimes I am not sure if it is impolite.

Comment: yeah, I think so. It is strange to add a title to my name, perhaps (Miss) Wei Li?

Comment: @Wei Ms. [or (Ms.)] would perhaps be more decorous today, since your marital status is not in question.

Comment: This is a subtle solution; maybe too subtle. Correspondents frequently spell my name incorrectly (Mathew vs Matthew) even though I write my own name in all of my replies. Sometimes I consider writing "Mattttthew" just to draw attention to it and make a point, but I've never actually gone through with it. Then again, "Miss" is easier to spot than a single extra 't'...

Answer (score 11):

I agree with the suggestion offered by Happy & StoneyB; that is, you could simply sign your name with "Ms.", and hope that he notices and gets the hint.

That said, your question asked about a good way to phrase it.

I think the best policy is to be gracious and try not to embarrass the other party. As for the use of "female," you could use that, or you could say "a woman" instead. Here's what I might recommend:

> By the way, I noticed you greeted me using "Mr." Perhaps there's a little mix-up there, as I am a woman. No offense taken.

You might also soften the blow by using an emoticon.

> By the way, I noticed you greeted me using "Mr." I just wanted to let you know that I'm a woman. But please don't worry about it. :-)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however, in the given context, one needs to be more careful, since the OP is probably just getting to know the professor, and written communication carries a high risk of misunderstanding, especially if it is the only or the main mode of communication between the two.

Comment: @Happy - I don't believe a professor would be offended by either of the suggestions I have provided here, and I think the meaning would be pretty clear.

Comment: It might just be me (and this probably goes a bit out of the scope of the question) but in text form (and even with the emoticon) your "No offense taken" sounds as if you really mean the opposite. My thought process is "Well if they really weren't offended, they probably wouldn't have even thought to mention it. At the very least, they must think that this is something which *could* be offensive." It sounds like a sort of back-handed chastisement, to me. I'd prefer the version with the emoticon, but not the final sentence. But that's just me, and I agree with everything else you've said!

Comment: @Wendi - Maybe that needs to be another question: If you're afraid someone might be embarrassed, and you want to assure them not to worry about it, how can you say so? As for me, if I assumed a She was a He, and the subsequently had to be informed otherwise, I'd be a little red-faced (embarrassed) about it, and I would appreciate a quick acknowledgement that says, "No harm, no foul," or "No biggie," or "Don't worry about it," or "No offense taken."

Comment: @J.R. Reading your comment, I think it actually might just be the fact that "no offense" is also used sarcastically that stood out to me. Your other suggestions don't sound negative to me at all. But since it's not uncommon to begin with "No offense, but..." and then say something offensive, I might have been making that connection in my mind. :)

Comment: I was thinking I could use a smiling face, too: :-), but I remember I read from the email etiquette that suggested: don't use emotion icon to your professor...

Comment: @Wei - In most cases, I would agree with that advice. Particularly when overused, emoticons can be regarded as childish and unprofessional. But this situation might warrant an exception, because, as I said in my earlier comment, the erroneous assumption might cause the professor some embarrassment, and it would be gracious of you to let him know that you weren't upset or bothered or offended.

Comment: @J.R. Written communication kills the non-verbal cues in the message, which could cause unwanted trouble. You never know if the recipient (the professor, in this case) is a happy-go-lucky person, or tends to be grumpy. Of course, the sender did not *intend* any offence, but it might still get interpreted that way. However, if you met them before (at least over phone), then written communication becomes smoother. Another example: If you and I post our photos instead of a flying blue cat and an orange respectively, we will "read" each other's comments differently. It's amazing how that happens!

Answer (score 6):

This is a recurring problem in email conversations for people with Chinese names, as when only seeing the English transliteration and not the actual Chinese character of the name, it can be impossible to infer the person's gender. 
In some business conversation I encountered, people would add a hint to their email signature, for example

> Li Wei (Ms.)
>   Title, function
>   Company name
>   Contact details

I don't know if you're using a signature, but this would definitely be a subtle way of letting the professor know that you're female and also of avoiding this problem in the future.
Maybe in this case, since the professor has presumably already seen your old signature, you could think about about explaining this to him in the postscriptum of your next email:

> PS: I happened to notice that you adressed me as Mr. Don't worry about it though, that's actually not the first time this has happened. Since my name makes it very easy for this to occur, I have now added a little hint to my signature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By email signature do you mean the one I write or the one that automatically goes with my every email?

Comment: I mean the one that you can set up to automatically be attached to the bottom of all your emails. I don't mean the final sentence of your email, which you will usually write manually, like "Best wishes, Name".

Answer (score 1):

For anyone curious to know how it ended, @wei [responded](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/16074/4):

> Thank you all for your answers and suggestions. I replied last night using happy's suggestions. The Professor replied me with even a Chinese sentence, if I translate it, it would be "Sorry, Miss Li, is it?" (and he also wrote English expressing similar meaning of apology)
>
> I really think it is not easy to keep email contact with foreign professors. Sometimes I think I should talk about academic questions in every email sometimes I think it is kind of unnatural.

Comment: Who was "happy" I have no idea... :)

Comment: it looks like "happy" has changed his name to "Masked Man".

Comment: @TonyK yes, you're right J.R says as much in his answer. I hadn't seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing more about the style of his answer would help focusing this diplomatic operation better, but Happy's excellent suggestion is almost surely the best bet.

If you still don't quite like it for some reason (you haven't marked it accepted), here's an alternative idea, that might work.

Assuming his answer was encouraging, and you are replying him because your case is proceeding (rather than to just tell him you are a woman ;) ), then that means a CV must be involved somewhere in the process. So, just add a field to your personal data section:

```
    Gender: female
```

(In case you've already submitted one without that, you can almost always find a way to re-send an updated/fixed version.)

Comment: It would be strange to explicitly list one's sex on a CV.  What I advise my students is to put "(Ms.)" or "(Mr.)" in front of their name to help the recipient.

Comment: Maybe, but that's not my invention. In the computer industry (where I work) people come from various countries, with cryptic names, and the "sex" field is not so rare, and it's been there exactly to prevent situations like what this topic is about.

Comment: @espertus BTW, just realized, that I used the word "Sex" instead of "Gender" in the suggestion above. With that "softening", I'd argue that it's not strange even for more conservative fields than technology, e.g. have a look at [this example](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/cvsamples/a/cvexample1.htm) (at about.com).

Comment: Also consider this: "While some of this information [like sex, age etc.] may be required in a *CV*, it should be left out of a *resume*." (found [here](http://jobsearch.about.com/od/resumetips/a/not-include-resume.htm); note that I was referring to CVs.)

Comment: I stand by what I said, even for CVs.  American employers are not supposed to consider gender, age, or other information not directly related to the job.  I'm a computer scientist and have been involved in many academic and industry job searches.  I rarely see demographic information on a CV except from foreigners.  Gender can be indicated more subtly with a parenthesized courtesy title.  Putting it next to the name also communicates that you're mentioning it only so you can be addressed properly.  Otherwise it can read like: Hire me because I'm a man/woman.

Comment: @espertus *American* employers. There are other countries in the world as well, and this site, by definition, is for international use. You have every right to stand by what you said in the context you are referring to, but don't assume that the answer is "wrong" simply because there are other places where your American customs don't apply.

Comment: @Happy, I am aware there are other countries.  That's why I said that what I'm familiar with is America in my second comment.  I tried to edit my first comment to add that qualification but seem unable to.

Answer (score 0):

This happens all the time in academia and in the business world, too.  I would just suggest always getting in the habit of putting Ms. in front of your name when there may even be the hint of an issue. I work at a university where there are lots of students coming and going and I see this all the time.

Believe me the professor is probably trying to be diligent and will definitely notice if there is a Ms. in front of the name the next time.  I know I would.  If it happens repeatedly after you start using the Ms. prefix, then I would explicitly call attention.  But probably not before. After all, at this point it is just a single character mistake in an email (Mr. vs. Ms.) and I would treat it as such until it is clear that the prof. is clearly not paying attention.

Comment: Thanks~ Should I use "Ms." or "Miss"?

Comment: @Wei - If this professor is in the U.S., use "Ms." "Miss" is rarely used here now, as some consider it to be a bit condescending. Apparently, your professor has enough trouble keeping the Mr.'s and the Ms.'s straight – I wouldn't recommend adding another dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know that. (Because in China, we never use "Ms." in front of a college student's name. If one has to use, it would be "Miss".)

Comment: Definitely use "Ms." in the United States.  I've only seen "Miss" used professionally by pre-college teachers.  I can't speak to other countries.

Answer (score -1):

If this happens from time to time, you may want to consider changing your email contact information so that your 'From' name in your email client is set to 'Ms. Wei Whatever.'  That way, you can still be informal in the body of your emails yet you are giving more information to new contacts in a perfectly acceptable and non-confrontational manner.

Comment: -1? Seriously??  How about a constructive comment, please?